# Properly check NSDictionary structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, coding-style, nsdictionary

I have to interact with a complex API and a complex JSON response. I'm using `AFNetworking` and the JSON response is automagically transformed into an `NSDictionary`.

I'm not sure what the JSON structure will always be as I'm expecting, so I started to write a lot of defensive code.

```
if (response &&
    [response isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] &&
    [[response valueForKey:@"result"] isKinfOfClass:[NSString class]]....
```

I'm wondering if can be useful write some code that takes an empty JSON response as a "template" and checks if the response will "match" with the template. Has someone already dealt with this kind of problem?

Comment: I would say forget validation of the JSON and instead write a custom model class that is populated by the parsed JSON data and then add a validation method to the custom model class.  This will pay dividends through the development of the app.

Comment: Of course i'm using custom classes, but this moves the problem in an another point, you always have to check if a key for the dictionary is present and if the value is a string, a bool, a number, an array or another dictionary because all those type are allowed in a JSON response.

Comment: Well my point is invest code in your model class and forget about the "transient data".  It's possible your model classes will be populated via Core Data or something else other than JSON and you can use your single validate method to check the model was populated properly.

Answer (score 1):

for inserting the values into Core Data from JASON response I have been using this category which can be used as function

```
@implementation NSManagedObject (safeSetValuesKeysWithDictionary)

- (void)safeSetValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)keyedValues
{
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[self entity] attributesByName];
    for (NSString *attribute in attributes) {
        id value = [keyedValues objectForKey:attribute];
        if (value == nil) {
            // Don't attempt to set nil, or you'll overwite values in self that aren't present in keyedValues
            continue;
        }
        NSAttributeType attributeType = [[attributes objectForKey:attribute] attributeType];
        if ((attributeType == NSStringAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])) {
            value = [value stringValue];
        } else if (((attributeType == NSInteger16AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger32AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSInteger64AttributeType) || (attributeType == NSBooleanAttributeType)) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value  integerValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSFloatAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSDateAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
            value = [dateFormat dateFromString:[[value componentsSeparatedByString: @"."] objectAtIndex:0]];
        } else if ((attributeType == NSDoubleAttributeType) && ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])) {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
        }

        [self setValue:value forKey:attribute];
    }
}

@end
```